# NpgsqlCommand over NpgsqlDataAdapter

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

Why would you use NpgsqlCommand over NpgsqlDataAdapter?

NpgsqlCommand usage, using reader

```
var _command = new NpgsqlCommand();
var _reader = _command.ExecuteReader();
...
while (_reader.Read())
{
...
```

NpgsqlDataAdapter usage, using Datasets

```
IDbDataAdapter dbDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
...
dbDataAdapter.Fill (dataSet);
```

[Basic](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) usage does not mention DataAdapter.
Is NpgsqlCommand and reader more efficient and should be preferred choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NpgsqlCommand is the more low-level API - you're responsible for providing the raw SQL, and also for reading the resultset via NpgsqlDataReader. DataAdapter/DataTable are a layer above that; it has some shortcomings (e.g. resultsets are buffered in memory) and in general is considered somewhat old/legacy. If what you want is to send SQL and read the results back, consider using NpgsqlCommand unless there's a good reason to use NpgsqlAdapter.